# How to disable HTTP/2 in Golang's standard http.Client, or avoid tons of INTERNAL_ERRORs from Stream ID=N?

Tags: go, http2

I want to send a fairly large number (several thousand) of HTTP requests ASAP, without putting too much load on the CDN (has an https: URL, and ALPN selects HTTP/2 during the TLS phase) So, staggering (i.e. time shifting) the requests is an option, but I don't want to wait TOO long (minimize errors AND total round-trip time) and I'm not being rate limited by the server at the scale I'm operating yet.

The problem I'm seeing originates from `h2_bundle.go` and specifically in either `writeFrame` or `onWriteTimeout` when about 500-1k requests are in-flight, which manifests during `io.Copy(fileWriter, response.Body)` as:

```
http2ErrCodeInternal = "INTERNAL_ERROR" // also IDs a Stream number
// ^ then io.Copy observes the reader encountering "unexpected EOF"
```

I'm fine sticking with HTTP/1.x for now, but I would love an explanation re: what's going on. Clearly, people DO use Go to make a lot of round-trips happen per unit time, but most advice I can find is from the perspective of the server, not clients. I've already tried specifying all the relevant time-outs I can find, and cranking up connection pool max sizes.

Comment: The docs mention `GODEBUG=http2debug=2` but I have no idea what to grep.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best guess at what's going on:

The rate of requests is overwhelming a queue of connections or some other resource in the HTTP/2 internals. Maybe this is fix-able in general or possible to fine tune for my specific use case, but the fastest way to overcome this kind of problem is to rely on HTTP/1.1 entirely, as well as implement limited retry + rate limiting mechanisms.

> Aside, I am now using a single retry and `rate.Limiter` from https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/time/rate#Limiter in addition to the "ugly hack" of disabled HTTP/2, so that outbound requests are able send an initial "burst" of M requests, and then "leak more gradually" at a given rate of N/sec. Ultimately, the errors from `h2_bundle.go` are just too ugly for end-users to parse. An expected/unexpected EOF should result in the client "giving it another try" or two, which is more pragmatic anyway.

As per the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#:%7E:text=The-,GODEBUG%20variables,-are%20not%20covered), the easiest way to disable h2 in Go's `http.Client` at runtime is `env GODEBUG=http2client=0 ...` which I can also achieve in other ways as well. Especially important to understand is that the "next protocol" is pre-negotiated "early" during TLS, so Go's `http.Transport` must manage that configuration along with a cache/memo to provide its functionality in a performant way. Therefore, use your own `httpClient` to `.Do(req)` (and don't forget to give your Request a `context.Context` so that it's easy to cancel) using a custom `http.RoundTripper` for Transport. Here's some example code:

```golang
type forwardRoundTripper struct {
    rt http.RoundTripper
}

func (my *forwardRoundTripper) RoundTrip(r *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return my.rt.RoundTrip(r) // adjust URLs, or transport as necessary per-request
}

// httpTransport is the http.RoundTripper given to a Client as Transport
// (don't forget to set up a reasonable Timeout and other behavior as desired)
var httpTransport = &customRoundTripper{rt: http.DefaultTransport}

func h2Disabled(rt *http.Transport) *http.Transport {
    log.Println("--- only using HTTP/1.x ...")
    rt.ForceAttemptHTTP2 = false // not good enough
    // at least one of the following is ALSO required:
    rt.TLSClientConfig.NextProtos = []string{"http/1.1"}
    // need to Clone() or replace the TLSClientConfig if a request already occurred
    // - Why? Because the first time the transport is used, it caches certain structures.
    // (if you do this replacement, don't forget to set a minimum TLS version)

    rt.TLSHandshakeTimeout = longTimeout // not related to h2, but necessary for stability
    rt.TLSNextProto = make(map[string]func(authority string, c *tls.Conn) http.RoundTripper)
    // ^ some sources seem to think this is necessary, but not in all cases
    // (it WILL be required if an "h2" key is already present in this map)
    return rt
}

func init() {
    h2ok := ...
    if t, ok := httpTransport.rt.(*http.Transport); ok && !h2ok {
        httpTransport.rt = h2Disabled(t.Clone())
    }
    // tweak rate limits here
}
```

This lets me make the volume of requests that I need to OR get more-reasonable errors in edge cases.